# Remove Expires header from Azure response

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api

I am using Azure API management to make API calls. Problem is that even though i have caching set to 1 hour azure appends a header called Expires to the current time. I am using Azure to expose the API calls to mobile devices. Because of this Expires header the devices will not cache the response.

How can i remove the Expires header from the Azure response??

Comment: If not explicitly removing a header how could i set a date time value on it. I would like to set the Expires header to datetime now + 1 hour so that it matches the cache policy expiration date.

Comment: Can you please post your cache policy?

Comment: <outbound>
  <base />
  <set-header name="Strict-Transport-Security" exists-action="override">
   <value>max-age:10</value>
  </set-header>
  <cache-store caching-mode="cache-on" duration="3600" />
  <set-header name="Pragma" exists-action="override">
   <value>public</value>
  </set-header>
  <set-header name="Cache-Control" exists-action="override">
   <value>public</value>
   <value>max-age:3600</value>
  </set-header>
 </outbound>

Comment: do you have a corresponding get from cache policy in your inbound? http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/api-management-policy-reference/#caching-policies

Comment: My inbound policy looks like this.<inbound><base /><cache-lookup vary-by-developer="false" vary-by-developer-groups="false"><vary-by-header>Accept</vary-by-header><vary-by-header>Accept-Charset</vary-by-header></cache-lookup></inbound>.